# How to Compare Substrings of Two Lists in Python

Tags: python, list, compare, substring

I have two lists, shortened for this example:

`l1 = ['Chase Bank', 'Bank of America']`

`l2 = ['Chase Mobile: Bank & Invest', 'Elevations Credit Union Mobile']`

I am trying to generate a list from l1 that is not in l2.
In this case; 'Bank of America' would be the only item returned.

Chase Bank (from l1) and Chase Mobile: Bank & Invest (from l2) are the same because they both contain the keyword 'Chase', so they wouldn't go into the exclusion list. But Bank of America should go into the list, even though 'Bank' appears both in 'Bank of America' and 'Bank & Invest'.

I have tried using `set`, just a `for` loop with `if/in` as well as using `any` with a `list comprehension`. I have also tried `regex`, but matching the pattern of substrings from one list to the other is proving to be very difficult for me.

Is this possible with Python or should I broaden my approach?

Comment: First you need to decide the rules for how every possible bank should be matched from l1 to l2. This is not a programming problem, until you have defined the rules - then you can write a program to implement them.

Answer (score 2):

Use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) to remove all undesired substrings from the elements of your first list. Here, I remove `bank`, case-insensitively, with optional whitespace before and after it. Then use another list comprehension, this time to remove everything that is found in the second list. Use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get both the index and the element from the list. Also, use [sets](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets), which is optional and makes the code faster for long and/or repetitive lists.

```
import re

lst1 = ['Chase Bank', 'Chase bank', 'Bank of America']
lst2 = ['Chase Mobile: Bank & Invest', 'Elevations Credit Union Mobile']
lst1_short = [re.sub(r'(?i)\s*\bbank\b\s*', '', s) for s in lst1]
print(lst1_short)
# ['Chase', 'Chase', 'of America']

lst1 = [s for i, s in enumerate(lst1) if
      not any(x for x in set(lst2) if lst1_short[i] in x)]
print(lst1)
# ['Bank of America']
```

Note: you can extend your list of stop words (here, only `bank`) using regular expressions. For example:

```
re.sub(r'(?i)\s*\b(bank|credit union|institution for savings)\b\s*', '', s)
```

Comment: This is a nice answer to a bad question and I've upvoted it. But, for example, what if `lst1` contains `'ECUM'` for `'Elevations Credit Union Mobile'` (or some other abbreviation)?  Or what if `lst1` contains `"Bank Credit Union"` - it will erroneously match `"Elevations Credit Union Mobile"`. All I am saying is the OP's real problem is probably not solvable with a single approach and needs careful testing to avoid incorrect results.

Comment: I've upvoted this answer too, thanks everyone for the help, and I agree it was a bad question, hopefully in the sense that there may be more to the answer than one solution rather than how I presented it, but I also agree that using this a single approach will need to be tested. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this:

```
l1 = ['Chase Bank', 'Bank of America']
l2 = ['Chase Mobile: Bank & Invest', 'Elevations Credit Union Mobile']

def similar_substrings(l1, l2):
    word1 = [l1[i].split(" ") for i in range(len(l1))]
    word2 = [l2[i].split(" ") for i in range(len(l2))]
    words_in = []

    for string in l1:
        for string2 in l2:
            is_in = True
            for word in string:
                if word not in string2:
                    is_in = False
            if is_in:
                words_in.append(string)

    return words_in

print(similar_substrings(l1, l2))
```

I only checked if sentences from `l2` were contained in `l1` but you can modify it pretty easily to check both inclusions.

Comment: this outputs an empty list?

Comment: now it outputs ```['Chase Bank']``` when the desired output is ```['Bank of America']``` and ```word1``` and ```word2``` are not accessed.

Comment: It depends on if you’re looking for the list of the words to reject or to accept

Comment: well surely you're looking for the list of words to accept? why would you want a list of words to reject

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a list comprehension:

```
l2_chase = any('Chase' in j for j in l2)
[i for i in l1 if not ('Chase' in i and l2_chase)]
```

Output:

```
['Bank of America']
```